# SourceTree ssh-agent path is wrong

Tags: git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I have updated SourceTree to version 1.6.15 and after that some paths where changed/messed up.
Before the update everything went without any issue.

Now the ssh-agent fails to start, the window closes automatically in a matter of milliseconds.

The logs in the sourcetree (sourcetree.log) show this log when I try to open the ssh-agent:

```
2015-07-13T09:30:32: Attempt to start ssh-agent.exe process [C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\usr\bin\ssh-agent.exe]
```

I have checked the path of the ssh-agent and it is wrong, it should be:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\ssh-agent.exe
```

I had been using SourceTree with the **System Git**.

The only way I had been able to fix the issue was by changing SourceTree options for Git and use the **Embedded Git**.

I want to avoid having two Git environments and use only the System Git. Is there a way to to change the path of the ssh-agent SourceTree tries to open?

If I use git from the command line, everything works fine, so I guess the Paths are all set up correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me as if this is a regression in [SourceTree version 1.6.15](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/update/WindowsReleaseNotes.html) while trying to [fix compatibility with the new Git for Windows 2.x](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-3226) (which has a slightly different directory layout).

The best solution IMO is to simply upgrade to [the latest Git for Windows 2.x pre-release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/latest). Don't get deterred by "pre-release", it's already in good shape, and brings you all the Git 2.x goodness.

**Edit:** Alternatively, upgrade to SourceTree version 1.6.17 which was just released.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. If there is no other way to change that path I will try with the new Git version as soon as I have time to make all the changes to the Git Environment.

Comment: I guess there would be different solutions, like using directory junctions or copying files, but simply upgrading Git for Windows definitely is the cleanest solution IMO. It also gives you all the benefits of running Git client 2.x.

Comment: SourceTree released an patch update which fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

SourceTree released a patch update with version **1.6.17** which fixes the wrong paths that create this issue.

If you choose to stick with an version lower than that, use the embedded Git environment or use the solution provided by **@sschuberth**.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, my solution is that going to Tools/Options, Git tab, "Use embedded Git" instead of "Use System Git". Hope it helps.

Comment: SourceTree released an patch update which fixes this issue.