# SourceTree ssh-agent failing after update

Tags: git, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

I just updated SourceTree to the most recent Windows version, 1.8.1. I wish I knew what version I was on previously, but I believe it was an early 1.7.x version, as there were several options for me to choose what to upgrade up to.

Previously SourceTree would launch the ssh-agent to ask for my credentials on every launch of the application, which was fine. Now, after the upgrade, a modal pops up with the error:

> 'ssh-agent' failed with code - 1: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   ()

Opening and closing the Options menu will also prompt the error modal, as will Tools -> Launch ssh-agent. I checked the log (sourcetree.log) to see if I could find a message that would indicate that this is the same problem as [this user had here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376965/sourcetree-ssh-agent-path-is-wrong), but instead, every time the application launches, there are either 22 or 44 entries of this identical message:

```
ERROR [2016-02-16 14:06:17,785] [1] [SourceTree.Bookmarks.BookmarkManager] [RegisterBookmarkEventHandlers] - RegisterAsRepositoryUpdatedEventHandler called with null repo
```

That message does not get logged every time the modal appears, only every time SourceTree is opened. I have gone through every repository I have bookmarked, and they all still do exist both locally and remotely. Under Tools -> Options I am set to be using OpenSSH as my SSH Client, my SSH key is set to the correct file path, and I am set to be using System Git.

Are there other log files, either SourceTree specific or from git or even OpenSSH, that I should look for that might give me more details on what's actually giving this NullReferenceException?

Comment: It seems that many things are broken with the new 1.8 version. For example, git flow fails without an error. I'm downgrading to 1.7 until the next version.

Comment: Atlassian tweeted the download link for the previous version here: https://twitter.com/sourcetree/status/699630309495738368

Comment: Oh good, really glad to see they're jumping on top of this right away. Looks like I'll be downgrading for the time being as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Updating my embedded git version fixed this issue for me as per the attached link.

I went from version 1.9.something to 2.6.1

[Atlassian Answers](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/36184067/how-to-reslove-ssh-agent-failed-with-code-1-system.nullreferenceexception-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-object.)

Comment: Awesome, looks like this fixed it. With how many other bugs there are being reported with 1.8.1, I'll probably still be downgrading to 1.7 for the time being. Still marking this as accepted of course as it does solve this problem.

Comment: Yeah, it's still super buggy. Git-flow is horribly broken for me, for example.

Answer (score 0):

After switching from embedded to system git, I started having this issue more often. Then, after reinstalling both SourceTree and Git, I started having this issue 100% of the time.

I remembered that during the system git install, I told git to use the system's OpenSSH. I reinstalled the system git, this time with its own embedded OpenSSH. Now things work as they should.